# Postgres function NULL value for row that references NEW

Tags: postgresql, triggers, null, plpgsql

I have a trigger setup to fire after a row is updated or inserted for table A. There is also a table B that references table A, but also has another column which I want to analyze, a boolean (so this function would only be usable on an `UPDATE`).

When I try to access the column:

```
SELECT col1 FROM B WHERE B.aID = NEW.ID;
```

This column `col1` is always NULL.

Why is this? How can I get the boolean value upon an update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you are running into a naming conflict. Parameter names (`IN` and `OUT` parameters) are visible in the function body (almost) anywhere and take precedence over unqualified column names. Did you declare `col1` as variable in the function?

To avoid the conflict, **table-qualify** the column name:

```
SELECT b.col1 FROM tableb b WHERE b.aID = NEW.ID;
```

This is good practice in any case.

It is also good practice to prefix variable names, so they wouldn't normally conflict with table columns. Like: `_col1`.

Comment: Bingo - my declared variable was indeed the same name as the column itself.  Adding an underscore before the name (_col1) for the local function variable solved it!  Thanks!